# mod_rewrite handling extra GET variables

Tags: mod-rewrite, get

I have a mod rewrite rule for pagination of my content:

```
RewriteRule ^content/page/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

However, I am also attempting to handle facebook connect, which will result in a url that looks like this:

```
http://content.local/page/2?session={"session_key"...
```

However, with my current rewrite rule, the session variable does not get passed along. How can I pass that variable in addition? I would want to un-rewritten link to look something like `/index.php?page=2&session={"session_key"...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the QSA flag like this:

```
RewriteRule ^content/page/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Boy, it's like they thought of that contengency. Thank you!